# Is there a way to check multiple variables in an array and only go forward if all of them are true? Swift language

Tags: arrays, swift

I have 2 arrays (start point) and (stop point) and one value generated by a for loop that should be placed between the start and the stop. Only if all the values are placed between start and stop should the answer be written to a new array.

```
var possible_values: [Double] = []
let array_start_point2 = [45.0,105.0,165.0,225.0,285.0]
let array_stop_point2 = [80.0,140.0,200.0,260.0,360.0]
let number_of_obstacles2 = 5

for n in stride(from: 500, to: 2000, by: 10) {
    for i in 0...number_of_obstacles2-1 {
    let stop_point = array_stop_point2[i]
    let start_point = array_start_point2[i]
    print("start: \(start_point)")
    print("stop: \(stop_point)")
    let value_mm = (Double(n)*Double(i+1))
    let value = value_mm/10
    print("value: \(value)")

    //This part is not working
    if value > start_point && value < stop_point  {
    //Only append to array if all 5 values are ok.
        possible_values.append(value) }
      
    
    }
}
```

this gives me the values:
start: 45.0
stop: 80.0
value: 50.0
start: 105.0
stop: 140.0
value: 100.0
start: 165.0
stop: 200.0
value: 150.0
start: 225.0
stop: 260.0
value: 200.0
start: 285.0
stop: 320.0
value: 250.0

Only if all the five criteria is meet then value 50 should be stored. Then test value 51...
I would be very grateful for any advice

Comment: What do mean by "between the start and the stop"?

Comment: This is incredibly hard to read code (`n`? `i`? `value`?). People won't be bale to help much until you tidy it up and make it more clear what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be easier to work with ranges and also to calculate each value for each range to check

```
let array_start_point2 = [45.0,105.0,165.0,225.0,285.0]
let array_stop_point2 = [80.0,140.0,200.0,260.0,360.0]
let ranges = zip(array_start_point2, array_stop_point2).map { $0.0...$0.1 }
var possibleValues: [Double] = []

for n in stride(from: 500, to: 2000, by: 10) {
    var shouldStore = true

    for (index, range) in ranges.enumerated() {
        if !range.contains(Double(n)*Double(index+1)/10) {
            shouldStore = false
            break
        }
    }
    if shouldStore { possibleValues.append(Double(n)/10) }
}
```

Comment: You should make use of `allSatisfy` and `filter`

Comment: This worked perfectly, it was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bool to track and then clear the values if they are not all true.  Something like below.

```
var possible_values: [Double] = []
let array_start_point2 = [45.0,105.0,165.0,225.0,285.0]
let array_stop_point2 = [80.0,140.0,200.0,260.0,360.0]
let number_of_obstacles2 = 5

for n in stride(from: 500, to: 2000, by: 10) {
    let allAreTrue = true //boolean assume they are all true
    var temp_possible_values: [Double] = [] //use a temporary array since you may or may not need the values from this stride
    for i in 0...number_of_obstacles2-1 {
        let stop_point = array_stop_point2[i]
        let start_point = array_start_point2[i]
        print("start: \(start_point)")
        print("stop: \(stop_point)")
        let value_mm = (Double(n)*Double(i+1))
        let value = value_mm/10
        print("value: \(value)")
        //This part is not working
        if value > start_point && value < stop_point  {
            //Only append to array if all 5 values are ok.
            temp_possible_values.append(value)
        } else {
            allAreTrue = false // as soon as one is not true set to false
            break //break out of the loop because you dont need to proceed further
        }
    }
    if(!allAreTrue) { //if they aren't all true then purge the list
       temp_possible_values.removeAll()
    }
    possible_values.addAll(temp_possible_values)
}
```

Comment: I am not able to use the `possible_values.addAll(temp_possible_values)` function. Do you have an advice how to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like you know so much about your inputs, that what you actually want is a `ClosedRange<Int>?`, not a `[Double]`.

Give `ƒ` a better name that actually describes what it's doing.

```swift
func ƒ(_ point: Int) -> Bool {
  zip(
    [45, 105, 165, 225, 285],
    [80, 140, 200, 260, 360]
  ).map(ClosedRange.init)
  .enumerated()
  .allSatisfy {
    $0.element.contains(point * ($0.offset + 1))
  }
}

let points = 50...200
let range =
  points.first(where: ƒ)
  .map { $0...points.last(where: ƒ)! }
```

Comment: This may have worked just fine, it is just a bit too complicated for my skill level to manage.

Comment: Sharpen your axe! 